# How to override / compliment ng-class in a directive with a template with replace: true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Without removing** `replace: true`, how can `ng-class` be used on the directive below without causing an error / conflict with the template `ng-class`?

Currently, this throws the following Angular error:

> Error: Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 16 of
>   the expression [{custom: true} {custom:settings=='custom', other:
>   settings=='other'}] starting at [{custom:settings=='custom', other:
>   settings=='other'}].

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <setting settings="settings.someProperty" 
    ng-class="{custom: true}" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    someProperty: ''
  }
});

myApp.directive('setting', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    // Removing this is NOT an option
    replace: true,
    require: '^myCtrl',
    template: '<div ng-class="{myclass:settings==\'custom\', other: settings==\'other\'}"><input type="radio"  name="mySetting" ng-model="settings" value="other" />TEST</div>',
    scope: {
      settings: '=',
    }
  };
});
```

[jsFiddle of this setup](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/3jcmLh0t/22/)

Comment: shouldn't that be {custom.settings == \'custom\' and other.settings==\'other\' ?

Comment: @DaveBush - No, the ng-class is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into angular's compile, we can see that this is a problem from the [mergeTemplateAttributes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0/src/ng/compile.js#L2595-L2602) function (your jsFiddle used v1.1.5, but this piece hasn't changed even up to v1.5.0). In fact there is [closed bug #7402](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7402) referencing the same problem. Quoting [@lgalfaso](https://github.com/lgalfaso) from that bug

> I would agree that this is an issue for ng-class just like it is an issue in all cases stated at [#7402 (comment)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7402#issuecomment-42683460) This is a known bug and a limitation with directives with replace: true

So in short, without some workaround you cannot do this. Note that replace is [DEPRECATED](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-), so you should really try to remove `replace: true`. However, you can hack it to work in your favor.

Instead of passing a string, you can pass a function to [template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-template-). This function will be executed with tElement and tAttrs. If you want to replace the attribute entirely, setting tAttrs.ngClass to an empty string will remove the conflict.

```
template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        tAttrs.ngClass="";
        return '<div ng-class="{custom:settings==\'custom\', other: settings==\'other\'}"><input type="radio"  name="mySetting" ng-model="settings" value="other" />TEST<br> <input type="radio"  name="mySetting" ng-model="settings" value="" />{{settings}}</div>'
},
```

Here is an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8e1d385y/). If you change `someProperty` to other, you'll see that it correctly changes the background to yellow

---

On the other hand, if you want to extend/merge the two conflicting directive's attribute values, it will be a little more involved and a little more overhead. It will still require setting tAttrs.ngClass to the empty string, but first adding it to the ng-class like so:

```
template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
    var newNgClass = "{custom:settings==\'custom\', other: settings==\'other\'}";
    var oldNgClass = tAttrs.ngClass;
    var mergedNgClass = "extend(" + oldNgClass + "," + newNgClass + ")";
    tAttrs.ngClass = "";
    return '<div ng-class="' + mergedNgClass + '"><input type="radio"  name="mySetting" ng-model="settings" value="other" />TEST<br> <input type="radio"  name="mySetting" ng-model="settings" value="" />{{settings}}</div>'
},
link: function(scope) {
    scope.extend = angular.extend;
}
```

Instead of merging two angular expressions strings, this relies on angular.extend which is not on the scope, so it must be added in the linking function. Here is another [example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kfwn1s86/)

Comment: Interesting.  In the real-life example that I've designed this question around, the element in question is actually a `th`, and the directive is an attribute, not an entity, so I can see why the author (it's [si-table](https://github.com/simplicitylabs/si-table)) has chosen to use `replace:true`.  Not sure - given their template - that turning off replace is even an option.  It would require some refactoring.

Comment: And the fact that I used the same `custom` class for both was a mistake in setting up the question.  In fact, I need to add a *new* class.

Comment: @cale_b I added more info on merging the two values into one for the directive. Its not the most elegant solution, but it works. Note if two keys are the same, it will override the parent's.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best way to do it but you can consider this a hack

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <setting settings="settings.someProperty" 
    ng-class="{custom: true," />
</div>
```

**SCRIPT :**

```
 var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    someProperty: ''
  }
});

myApp.directive('setting', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    // Removing this is NOT an option
    replace: true,
    require: '^myCtrl',
    template: '<div ng-class="custom:settings==\'custom\', other: settings==\'other\'}"><input type="radio"  name="mySetting" ng-model="settings" value="other" />TEST</div>',
    scope: {
      settings: '=',
    }
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3jcmLh0t/10/

the ng-class become :{custom: true, custom:settings=='custom', other: settings=='other'} .

the custom condition is defined 2 times the second one will take control.

Comment: That's a very interesting answer.  I had not considered doing something like that.  As you say, it feels like a "hack", but sometimes that's the best you can ask / hope for.

Comment: yeah when you use replace:true the ng-class of parent is concatenated to the template ng-class .

Answer (score 0):

Here it is another solution (without any hack)

See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3gqjck49/4/

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    someProperty: ''
  }
});

myApp.directive('setting', function() {
   return {
   restrict: 'E',
   // Removing this is NOT an option
   replace: true,
   require: '^myCtrl',
   template: '<div ng-class="{custom:settings==\'custom\', other: settings==\'other\'}"><input type="radio"  name="mySetting" ng-model="settings" value="custom" />TEST<br> <input type="radio"  name="mySetting" ng-model="settings" value="other" />{{settings}}</div>',
   scope: {
     settings: '=',
   }
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3gqjck49/4/

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference in your code in this answer - can you hilight / explain it? Also, it appears you've pulled the `ng-class` out of the html - I need it there, because this directive is used in many different places with many different potential conditions / classes.

Comment: @cale_b in this case I think the logic to deal with these conditions and classes should be treated inside the directive itself. I believe that's the natural place to put this logic. It doesn't make a lot of sense to have that "ng-class" on the directive HTML if that DOM element will be replaced anyway. You could probably change the class dynamically using the directive logic.